# Whether the workflow of using Git and gitHub for cooperating project looks like as follows?

Tags: git

In a simple case, there should be at least three branches created locally.

1. First is the local repository for all commits
2. Second is a repository that I am working for
3. Third is used to fetch the remote repository

Here is my assumption about workflow for keeping code integrity and continuous development of the project in the decentralized repository for a group of people (GitHub).

1. Jump to branch 3, do the `git fetch`
2. Jump to branch 2, do the `git merge branch_3` and do integrity
   validation
3. Jump to branch 1, do the `git merge branch_2` and do integrity
   validation
4. Stay to branch 1, do the `git push` to upload the local repository
   to the remote repository. Maybe need to do integrity validation and even worst case, loopback 1-4 if someone pushed their local repository faster than you.

Comment: Pls read this 2010 [git development model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) What you are doing doesn’t really work.

Comment: Your usage of the words "branch" and "repository" seems to suggest you think they are the same, which is not true.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-flow

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows , https://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows , https://medium.com/javarevisited/5-different-git-workflows-50f75d8783a7

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article on [git branching with develop and master branches.](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) This is a commonly used approach for defining workflow with developer teams.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your concise reply. but according to the article, it seems there can be an unlimited same structure repository created depending on how many developers participate in the project. So my question is that in the master branch in the origin repository (maybe in GitHub), did they need to "git push" other branches to the origin as frequently as master and develop?  in this scenario, is it in origin a lot of branches about a different version of the above specific branches?